# A regex to identify spans with given class names

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am in the process of writing a custom BBCode editor (I have excellent reasons for doing this and not using a readymade effort) which generates, amongst other things HTML markup such as

```
<span class='className'>...</span>
```

All of this is done and works well.  However, I also need to do the reverse transformation from HTML to my BBCode where from time-to-time I need to identify all spans that use a given classname.  For example

```
<span class='classNameA' style='font-family"Arial"'>Span content</span> so I can convert it to my BBCode markup

[font=Arial]Span Content[/font]
```

I am well aware of the dangers of using regexs to parse any old HTML and that is not my intent.  I just need to reverse parse my own HTML tags - with everything else passing through to the BBCode editor display.

To cut a long story short - I am no good with regexs particularly those that require lookaheads etc.  I would much appreciate any help with creating a JavaScript regex for this job.

Comment: Why not use `document.getElementsByClassName("classNameA")` or jQuery and `$(".classNameA").text()`

Comment: What are your excellent reasons?

Comment: Just save the uncompiled BBCode alongside the HTML in your DB, then when the user edits use the BBCode and just compile it to HTML when needed. The space overhead isn't that big and it's totally easier and makes more sense, not everything can be translated exactly the way it was before often.

Comment: Excellent reasons - I require a number of custom extensions that do not form part of the classic BBCode spec.

Comment: I have considered saving BBCode instead of/alongside the HTML.  The problem is that I already have an established user base that has data saved in HTML (with no BBCode alongside).  I was thinking of providing a seamless transition where the old style HTML shows up partially translated whilst the new style is correctly translated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you either use Benjamin's suggestion and store the bb codes somewhere.

Alternatives to your regex would be innerHTMl or textContent from

```
document.querySelectorAll("span.classNameA");
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName("classNameA");
```

or if you use jQuery you can use

```
$(".classNameA").text()
```

and

```
$(htmlString).find(".classNameA").each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text(); 
});
```

without creating a DOM

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  How can I parse HTML without having jQuery add it to the DOM?  I suppose I could add the HTML to a placeholder element do the parsing and then clear the element.  But can it be done without the HTML ever going into the DOM at all?

Comment: You can do $(htmlString).find(".classNameA") without creating a DOM

Comment: Thanks - and also for stopping me from erring down the regex route.  Life would be so much harder without Stackoverflow